# PHP How to calculate the current display of paginated content

Tags: php, pagination

this should be really simple but I can just not figure it out at the moment - I have searched and can't find the right helping - maybe it's my wording of my problem which is the issue - I know this is simple but as I have said I am brain dead at the moment!

this is what I want
`Displaying 1 - 7 of 21 items`

if there are 21 products in total with 7 per page it needs to say

1 - 7 of 21 on page one
8 - 14 of 21 on page two
15 - 21 of 21 on page three

pretty sure that is the right way to step up? anyway any help would be appreciated! and I can put a bounty on this - although small at least it's something! thanks

Comment: I take it you are using the `limit` syntax to return only 7 rows of data, so keep track of your user by using something like `limit 0,7` in your first query, returning `$skip=1` to the next page as a variable to be sent to the `$_GET`, then in your PHP code, interpret the `$skip` to modify your query to something like `select blah blah... limit".($skip*7).",7;` and your next query will be `select blah blah... limit 7,7` which means it will skip the first 7 rows and return the next 7.

Comment: the code to paginate the query is all fine and working - just displaying this info is giving me brain freeze - thanks!

Comment: Okay, see other answers posted, this question got quick replies.

Comment: ye it did - thanks to every one for being so quick! and thanks Fluffeh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know what page you're on, and the number of entries per page, you can calculate it:

```
$limit = 7;
$page = 2;
$total = 21;

$upper = min( $total, $page * $limit);
$lower = ($page - 1) * $limit + 1;
printf( "Displaying %d - %d of %d on Page %d\n", $lower, $upper, $total, $page);
```

Now, just loop over pages 1 - 3 to [**see the output**<sup>Codepad</sup>](http://viper-7.com/kDsmjK):

```
Displaying 1 - 7 of 21 on Page 1
Displaying 8 - 14 of 21 on Page 2
Displaying 15 - 21 of 21 on Page 3
```

**Edit:** Using the OP's variables:

```
$upper = min( $products_total, $pager_current * $limit);
$lower = ($pager_current - 1) * $limit + 1;
printf( "Displaying %d - %d of %d on Page %d\n", $lower, $upper, $products_total, $pager_current);
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't work - last page displays wrong numbers

Comment: just looked and yes it does work on there - I have all the same setup in code im sure - just different var names - will check now again - sorry

Comment: Not a problem - I just updated my answer with what I believe is the correct variable names that you're using, and you can see the result on [this new codepad](http://viper-7.com/YL50Km).

Comment: thanks - I did change them already to match mine but it was still giving me odd results - I think just me !

Comment: can confirm that works fine when on all pages except last link in the pagination - it displays 6 - 7 instead of 7 - 7 but other than that it works fine! and sorted the last bit out already! thanks - how do you give bounties on here? thanks

Comment: Actually, there was a bug in my implementation - I fixed it, can you check to see if it works now? Here's the [updated codepad](http://viper-7.com/Y0fnFf).

Comment: thanks @nickb that works fine now! although I am using a different bit of code now - it does work and thanks for your time! very much appreciated - to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

```
$page = 0;
$max = 7;
$total = 21;

$totalPages = ceil($total / $max); // 3 pages
$currentRange = ($max*$page)+1 . " - " . ($max*($page+1));

echo $currentRange . " of " . $total;
```

I prefer starting `$page` at 0 and going up from there. It's pretty simple math.

Values of `$currentRange` up to 2 would be

```
1 - 7 of 21
8 - 14 of 21
15 - 21 of 21
```

Comment: hi Markus - thanks but think you have not understood my question properly - I know how to do the simple pagination stuff - that's fine - just displaying x - x of x total is my current issue. thanks

Comment: sorry Marcus - please forgive me I totally missed your currentRange line when reading - really busy and just missed it! will give it a go and let you know - thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You know the Total Products you have:

```
$total=21;
```

You know the page you are on:

```
$cur_page=2;
```

You know the items on one page:

```
$itemcount=7;
```

Print that:

`echo 'Displaying '.($itemcount*($cur_page-1)+1).' - '.$itemcount*$cur_page.' of '.$total.' items.'`;

Answer (score 0):

think this is working for me - seems to show the results I want no matter limit set

`$display_end = ($pager_current * $limit);

$display_start = ($display_end - $limit) + 1;`

if($pager_current == $pager_max){

$display_end = $products_total; //not great but works!

}

$displaying = 'Displaying '.$display_start.' - '.$display_end.' of '.$products_total.' items';

gives me the following output

Displaying 1 - 5 of 7 items
Displaying 6 - 7 of 7 items

when I have 7 total products and paginated at 5 per page or

Displaying 1 - 2 of 7 items
Displaying 3 - 4 of 7 items
Displaying 5 - 6 of 7 items
Displaying 7 - 7 of 7 items

when total products is 7 and paginated by 2 per page